# Page numbering in Word 365 is ignoring section break

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, office365

I am trying to do something that should be simple: start counting page numbers from the second page in the document (page 2 = 1), but not show the page numbers until my introduction in page 12.

I added a section break before the introduction, unchecked "link to previous" in the header, inserted page number in header and then... The page number only shows in the introduction page and ignores the next pages. If I go to the next page and insert page numbers, it shows up in all of the next pages, however, when I do this, the page numbers also show up on all previous pages before my introduction, which were not supposed to be showing up. Isn't this the whole point of inserting a new section (break -> next page) and unlinking to previous?

How do I make this work? I am stunned something so trivial could be made complicated by MS, truly amazing.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer? Do you have questions?

Answer (score 1):

### Page numbering is controlled in Word by Sections.

It is normally in headers or footers. It is not complicated until you start doing sections. Here is [my writing on Page Numbering in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers).

You would want a section break before you want the page numbering to start showing.
Unlink the header/footer that will have the page numbers in that new section from previous before you do anything with page numbers. In that section (where you want the page numbers displayed) Insert > Page Number > Format Page Numbers and tell Word where to start page numbering.

Here is the best set of directions for [numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm) by MVP Suzanne Barnhill. You can use those without adding the Roman numerals to your front matter.

### If you use "[Different First Page](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Different_First_Page)" or "[Different Even and Odd](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Odd_and_Even)" settings it gets even more complex.

Each section has three headers and three footers which can be displayed using these settings. These are independent of one another and each header and each footer has its own "[Link to Previous](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#LinkPrevious)" setting.

The interactions of these settings is described in my [Header and Footer Settings Recap](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings).

> This is confusing. This is because it really is complex to allow users
> the flexibility they need. If you don't need that complexity, probably
> you will never see it.

> - To understand what is happening in
>   headers and footers you need to know about Sections and Section
>   breaks. Header and footer coding is stored in the Section break that
>   follows the Section.
> - You probably want to turn on display of
>   non-printing formatting marks or work in normal or draft view so you
>   can see Section breaks. [Show non-printing characters](http://www.addbalance.com/word/nonprinting.htm).
> - Section
>   breaks do not always start a new page. Section breaks may be inserted
>   by Word without notice when you change columns, margins, page
>   numbering, or page orientation within a document.
> - There are four kinds of Section breaks; the most common are continuous
>   and new page. The other two start a new Section on either an
>   even-numbered or an odd-numbered page. The blank page that can be
>   generated by such a Section break will not have Headers or footers; it
>   will be a blank page. If you need Headers/footers on these pages,
>   Microsoft recommends insertion of a manual page break immediately
>   before the Section break to force a blank page with Headers/footers.
>   Otherwise, see John McGhie's article: [Create a non-blank, even-numbered page at the end of a chapter](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/InsEvnPgEndChap.htm)
> - Manual page breaks
>   do not change Header/footer settings. New-page Section breaks can, as
>   can continuous (no new page) Section breaks. (All Section breaks carry
>   Header/footer settings.)
> - Every Section will have three
>   different Headers and three different footers even if you never see
>   them. Because of this, and because there can be multiple Sections on a
>   single page, it may be easiest to temporarily expand each Section to
>   at least three pages (to see the First-Page, Even-Page, and Odd-Page
>   Headers and footers. This way you can see what is in each
>   Header/footer and what the settings are. You can temporarily expand
>   the number of pages using manual page breaks (Ctrl+Enter)
> - Section formatting is contained in the Section break that
>   follows the Section. If you delete all Section breaks you can find in
>   a document your formatting will be contained in the last paragraph
>   mark in the document, which is the last Section break.
> - If
>   there is a Section break on a page, changes to the Header/footer that
>   follow that Section break may not have any effect on the Header for
>   the page that contains the Section break. (Those settings or changes
>   are stored in the next Section break, the one governing that Section.)
>   Whether changes to the next header change the previous one depend on
>   the Link-to-previous setting of the next header.
> - If you have
>   a Section break on a page, the header and footer for that page will be
>   governed by the settings for the first Section on that page, even if
>   that Section contains no text (i.e., the page starts with a Section
>   break).
> - The Link-to-previous setting is specific to the type
>   of Header/footer: Primary Header, First-Page Header, and Even-Page
>   Header, Primary Footer, First-Page Footer, Even-Page Footer. Link to
>   previous is the default setting.
> - Link to previous is specific
>   to Headers and footers (can be different). It is also specific to each
>   type of Header/footer. That is, the first-page Header can be linked to
>   previous but not the first-page footer and not the even-page Header.
>   The Link-to-previous setting can be set for each Header/footer in
>   every Section after the first. This setting can be different in each
>   type of Header / footer in each Section.
> - Since each Section
>   has three different Headers and three different footers and the link
>   to previous setting is specific to the type of Header or footer, each
>   Section can have up to six different link-to-previous settings. This
>   is true even if the Header/footer to which it applies is not visible.
>   This is true even if the Section involved is a continuous Section in
>   the middle of a page and has no Headers or footers displayed.
> - The different-first-page setting covers both Headers and
>   footers and is a Section (not document) setting. This setting is
>   carried over into a new Section started from a Section set for
>   different-first-page.
> - Different odd and even covers both
>   Headers and footers and is a document (not Section) setting. Enabling
>   this for the first time renames each "header" into the "odd-page
>   header" and each "footer" into the "odd-page footer." The even-page
>   headers and footers will now be displayed. They will normally be blank
>   and you will have to add content.
> - Each Section can have
>   different settings for the distance from the edge of the page for the
>   Sections Headers and footers. The default is .5 inches.
> - Size:
>   The page layout settings reserve room for headers and footers. Even if
>   there is no header or footer, that reserved space will not be filled
>   by the body text. However, if you put more in a header or footer than
>   the space reserved, the body text will not overwrite it. The header or
>   footer will be allowed that space. This includes space-after or
>   space-before formatting of the line closest to the body text.

*NOTE: Most of the links are to my website's page on Sections.*